# Defining a module in Prolog

Tags: module, prolog

I have some problems defining a module. Here's a short reduction of the code:

```
:- module(my_module, [word/1]).
:- module(my_module, [alias_of/2]).

alias_of(A, B) :-
        alias_of(A, C),
        alias_of(C, B).
alias_of('Word_1', 'Word_2').

word(A) :-
        alias_of(B, A),
        word(B).
word('Word_1').
word('Word_3').
```

And this is the SWI-Prolog output when I **consult** the file:

```
1 ?- ERROR: (i:/dev/prolog-workspace/trial.0.pro:2):
        Undefined procedure: my_module:module/2
            However, there are definitions for:
                module/1
Warning: (i:/dev/prolog-workspace/trial.0.pro:2):
        Goal (directive) failed: my_module:module(my_module, [alias_of/2])
```

I thought, from the tutorials I read, that exposing predicates could be done using **:- module(module_name,[predicate_name/arity])**. What's wrong ?

EDIT: as I have played with this code now and tested it as a module, I figured out it's completely bugged...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*module* must be the first directive, and must appear just once.

```
:- module(my_module, [word/1, alias_of/2]).
... etc...
```

Comment: Extremely basic prolog question: what does the `/` after each ... function? mean?

Comment: @minseong it is the arity of the predicate. If a predicate takes 1 argument, then it's arity is 1. If a predicate takes 3 arguments, then its arity is 3. A predicate is true or false.